# Making the HERE Map activity works along with another activity

Tags: android-studio, here-api

I have a class for Turn by Turn Navigation with Voice Instructions, I want to run this activity in the background so the voice instructions work while another activity in the foreground is working,
how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an Android [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and put the [NavigationManager](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/map-guidance.html) related code in the service. That will allow your application to have TbT guidance while in the background or while showing other activities.